# Component is not visible in <lightning-layout-item> spread

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning, javascript, lightning-web-components

Im trying to place a custom object lookup on a page.
its working as a standalone component but not working when i keep in an existing LWC component

Lookup code:

```
<div>
<lightning-record-edit-form
object-api-name="ISF_Form_Request__c"
id="createCompForm"
>
<lightning-input-field
field-name="WD_Worktags__c"
variant="label-hidden"
onchange={handleAccountSelection}
required
>
</lightning-input-field>
</lightning-record-edit-form>

</div>
```

Existing component has a section with

```
<lightning-layout multiple-rows="true" horizontal-align="spread"> <lightning-layout-item size="12" medium-device-size="6" padding="around-small" \> <lightning-input type="text" label="Text ID" max-length="10" class="initiatorUSCIdInput" required value={fRequest.Initiator\_\_ID\_\_c} disabled \> </lightning-input> </lightning-layout-item>
```

Im confused of how to place my lookup code in this section

Just so you know when i tried the below code for standard object in the existing LWC component it worked fine
ex:

```
<div
class="slds-box slds-p-top_small"
style="background-color: white"
>
<lightning-record-edit-form
object-api-name="Contact"
id="createContactForm"
>
<lightning-input-field
field-name="AccountId"
variant="label-hidden"
onchange={handleAccountSelection}
required
>
</lightning-input-field>
</lightning-record-edit-form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation for lightning-layout-item:
You can place HTML tags and text between the lightning-layout-item components, but you can't place other components or expressions between them.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-layout/documentation

You can utilize the `slds-grid` class and styling to replicate the layout functionality:
https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/grid/